# Run a group task from previous task list result

Tags: celery

I have been trying to execute a pipeline using celery. Initial task should create a list of items to process and I would use group to further parallelize each item processing. Finally I should collect results from group task.

```
@app.task()
def prepare():
    return [item1, item2, item3]

@app.task()
def parallel_process(items, additional_param):
    return group(process.s(i, additional_param) for i in items)() # I get an error kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type GroupResult is not JSON serializable

@app.task()
def process(i, param):
    return mapping_func(item, param)

@app.task()
def collect(results):
    print(results)

pipeline = prepare.s() | parallel_process.s(param) | collect.s()
pipeline.apply_async()
```

I get an error **kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type GroupResult is not JSON serializable**

Process task gets called, but collect task does not. Final result never comes. Is there any other way of doing this? Could not find appropriate example online.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you should change `CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER` to `pickle`, because `GroupResult` type is not JSON serializable.

Reference: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#result-serializer

Comment: I changed `CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER` to pickle but I get same error. I think this is not a serialization issue, but the way grouping is done.

Comment: @alexv Try this one, `CELERY_SERIALIZER`? https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html

Comment: Nope, still the same.